# How to display an icon in the center of buttom navigation bar without label in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am trying to have a buttom navigation bar in flutter where one of the items has no label but I still want to see it in the center. It is the second item from the left.

Here is current code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/sample_screen/SampleScreen.dart';
import '../shared/TYMColors.dart';

class buttonNavBar {
  final int currentIndex;
  final bool LightMode;

  const buttonNavBar(
      {Key? key, required this.currentIndex, required this.LightMode});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items = [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: LightMode
              ? Image.asset('assets/Home_lt.png', height:24, width: 24)
              : Image.asset('assets/Home_dt.png', height:24, width: 24),
          activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/Home_sl.png', height:24, width: 24),
          label: 'Home'),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:
      Align(alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,child:
      Text("T⅄M", style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    color: LightMode ? Colors.white : Palette.tymButtomNavBarDarkText,
    fontSize: 18),),),
          activeIcon:
    Align(alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,child:
    Text("T⅄M", style: TextStyle( fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Palette.kToDark[800], fontSize: 18),),),
          label: ''
      ),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: LightMode
              ? Image.asset('assets/Alarm_lt.png', height:24, width: 24)
              : Image.asset('assets/Alarm_dt.png', height:24, width: 24),
          activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/Alarm_sl.png', height:24, width: 24),
          label: 'Alarm'),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: LightMode
              ? Image.asset('assets/Profile_lt.png', height:24, width: 24)
              : Image.asset('assets/Profile_dt.png', height:24, width: 24),
          activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/Profile_sl.png', height:24, width: 24),
          label: 'Profile'),
    ];
    
      return Container(
        height: 90.0,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: LightMode
              ? Palette.tymButtomNavBarLight
              : Palette.tymButtomNavBarDark,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
        child: SizedBox(height: 50, child: BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: items,
        selectedFontSize: 0.0,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Palette.kToDark[800],
            fontSize: 10),
        selectedItemColor: Palette.kToDark[800],

        unselectedItemColor: LightMode
            ? Colors.white
            : Palette.tymButtomNavBarDarkText,
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: LightMode ? Colors.white : Palette.tymButtomNavBarDarkText,
            fontSize: 10),
        onTap: (index) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
              SampleScreen(currentIndex: index, LightMode: LightMode,)));
        },
      ),),);
    }
  }
}
```

This is current ouptut:

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Is it possible using flutter's BottomNavigationBar or I need to create my own widget?

Comment: Surround the item with a Row and give it a MainAixsAlignment to center

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Align' widget does not have a height, it's just as small as possible.

Giving your Align widget some kind of height, either by using a 'SizedBox' or maybe even a 'Expanded' (Although im not sure) should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

All labels can be hidden, not only for a certain bar item. When all labels are hidden for selected and unselected cases they naturally will be aligned.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  showSelectedLabels: false,
  showUnselectedLabels: false,
  items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
...
  ]
)
```